# StatFs returns different size from setting

Tags: java, android, filesystems

I am trying to get the storage space on Android. Here is the solution I found.

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath())
stat.getTotalBytes()
```

It returns `774 MB` while the setting app shows`1 GB`. In AVD Manager, size on disk is `1 GB`. Is it possible to get the same value like setting app?

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
StatFs stat1 = new StatFs("YOUR PATH HERE");
    long bytesAvailable1 = (long) stat1.getAvailableBlocks() * (long) stat1.getBlockSize();
    double spaceAvailableInSD1 = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(bytesAvailable1 / 1073741824d));  //return MB.
```

I am getting exact available storage space in my case.

Comment: `getTotalBytes()` is `getBlockCountLong() * getBlockCountLong()` if you read the source code. Also, I am running the code on Android 8 Emulator. You should try to run your code on it first.

Comment: @Joshua Did you mean getBlockSizeLong()*getBlockCountLong() is how getTotalBytes() is implemented in the source?

Comment: @itisravi https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/StatFs.java

Comment: well, that seems to be the problem then. If you want the total size, you would need to f_blocks * f_bsize as defined in `man 2 statfs`.

Comment: Okay, I'm getting identical results for `buf.f_blocks*buf.f_bsize` and `buf.f_blocks*buf.f_frsize` on a linux box, so not sure what is going on here. What filesystem type is your ExternalStorageDirectory?

Answer (score -3):

below are methods to check if there is external sd-card  available, total space and free space in internal storage and external sd- card

```
public boolean isExternalSDCardAvailable() {
    String secStore = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
    if (secStore != null) {
        File f_secs = new File(secStore);
        return f_secs.exists();
    } else return false;
}

public long getAvailableInternalMemorySize() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath());
        long bytesAvailable = stat.getBlockSizeLong() * stat.getFreeBlocksLong();
        return bytesAvailable / (1024 * 1024);
    } else {
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath());
        long bytesAvailable = (long) stat.getBlockSize() * (long) stat.getFreeBlocks();
        return bytesAvailable / (1024 * 1024);
    }
}

public long getTotalInternalMemorySize() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath());
        long bytesAvailable = stat.getBlockSizeLong() * stat.getBlockCountLong();
        return bytesAvailable / (1024 * 1024);
    } else {
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath());
        long bytesAvailable = (long) stat.getBlockSize() * (long) stat.getAvailableBlocks();
        return bytesAvailable / (1024 * 1024);
    }
}

public long getAvailableExternalMemorySize() {
    String secStore = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
    File f_secs = new File(secStore);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(f_secs.getPath());
        long bytesAvailable = stat.getBlockSizeLong() * stat.getAvailableBlocksLong();
        return bytesAvailable / (1024 * 1024);
    } else {
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(f_secs.getPath());
        long bytesAvailable = stat.getBlockSize() * stat.getAvailableBlocks();
        return bytesAvailable / (1024 * 1024);
    }

}

public Long getTotalExternalMemorySize() {
    String secStore = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
    File f_secs = new File(secStore);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(f_secs.getPath());
        long bytesAvailable = stat.getBlockSizeLong() * stat.getBlockCountLong();
        long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / (1024 * 1024);
        return megAvailable;
    } else {
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(f_secs.getPath());
        long bytesAvailable = stat.getBlockSize() * stat.getBlockCount();
        long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / (1024 * 1024);
        return megAvailable;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please read the question before answering (copy-paste). I **KNOW** `StatFs`. I am asking **WHY** it is different from the value display in Setting App.